# Syntax Error for List Comprehension in Python, could not quite figure out what is wrong

Tags: python, syntax, list-comprehension

here is a piece of simplified code for a problem I am working on. I could not figure out what is wrong with the syntax for List Comprehension here. Can anyone help?

```
for i in range(10):
    a = [j if j == i for j in range(100)]



File "<ipython-input-19-4bf2e143eb37>", line 2
    a = [j if j == i for j in range(100)]
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

EDIT: Apparently I have my syntax flipped in the above example, as the 'if' statement should go after the 'for' statement.
However, I also realize a quirky thing here in that if the 'if' statement also contains an 'else' statement, then it could go before the 'for' statement, as in the example below. Not sure if there is any logic behind this.

```
l = [22, 13, 45, 50, 98, 69, 43, 44, 1]
[x+1 if x >= 45 else x+5 for x in l]
```

Any thought on this?

Comment: you have the format of the list comprehension flipped.

Comment: There are three different `if`s: 1. a control structure, follow by an expression and `:` 2. the ternary operator: `<value1> if <expression> else <value2>` 3. in the condition part of a comprehension. No not confuse these three!

Answer (score 0):

Unsure on your exact objective, but try:

```
for i in range(10):
    a = [j for j in range(100) if j == i ]
```

Comment: By the way I have some further discussion in my edit, any thought?

Comment: I'd be careful to make sure that you are getting the right result, as i dont think they are equivalent logical statements, although they look similar

Comment: Yeah, I just find it curious that it makes a difference whether the 'if' is put before or after and could not think of any example to highlight that difference right now. Like you said, probably they are not equivalent after all. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
 for i in range(10):
   a = [j for j in range(100) if j == i]
   print(a)
```

Comment: Thx friend!  Would love to hear your thought on my EDIT.